# How to decrypt a .pgp file using php cli

Tags: php, gnupg

It's the first time I need to do this.

I have to code a script in php to run with cli, the script is passed a .zip file which I have to decompress, the files inside are .pgp files and I need to decrypt these files, I have the following code.

```
function decryptPGPFiles($pgpFiles, $passphrase){
  $res = gnupg_init();
  foreach($pgpFiles as $filename){
    gnupg_adddecryptkey($res,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",$passphrase);
    $cipher = file_get_contents($filename);
    $plain = gnupg_decrypt($res,$cipher);
    var_dump($plain);
    die;
  }
}
```

Of course the 'var_dump($plain);' and 'die;' are just for testing. Anyway the $plain is always false. Assume that $pgpFiles is an array of filenames for the .pgp files in the current dir.

I do have a private key with name 'private.gpg' in the current dir and also I know the $passphrase.

I know that the 2nd parameter for the function 'gnupg_adddecryptkey' is a $fingerprint according to php.net, when I run 'gpg --import private.gpg' and then 'gpg --fingerprint' it appears the respective fingerprint and that's the one I'm passing as parameter, anyway the fingerprint appears with several blankspaces and I trim them.

I'm sure I'm not doing the right steps, but I can't find a documentation clear enough for me. It is even possible to decrypt a .pgp file from php cli?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: the private key is imported to the system user's GnuPG home directory used for running the script (might be different for development and the web server context)? What's the result of `gpg --list-secret-keys`, is the key referenced by the fingerprint listed?

Comment: When I do `gpg --list-secret-keys` I do see the imported secret key. Anyway I tried so much without functionality that I gave up on it and instead I used `exec()` to use the linux command line from php and that was it.

Answer (score 2):

According to a comment on the documentation:

[gnupg_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-decrypt.php)

*Mike*

*As of gnupg version 2, it is not possible to pass a plain password any more. The parameter is simply ignored. Instead, a pinentry application will be launched in case of php running in cli mode. In cgi or apache mode, opening the key will fail.
The simplest solution is to use keys without passwords.*

Personally, I probably wouldn't use a key without a password as stated above though. I'm still looking for a better solution but something like this has worked for now:

```
shell_exec("gpg --batch --passphrase \"" . $passphrase . "\" -d $file > $decrypted_file_name");
```

Consider using this with escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() if passing in potentially dangerous variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking [`gnupg_geterror()`](http://php.net/gnupg-geterror) after [`gnupg_adddecryptkey()`](http://php.net/gnupg-adddecryptkey)? I suspect your private key is not actually getting accepted. I assume it needs to be in PHP user's GPG keyring (i.e. whatever or whoever is invoking the script, not necessarily your GPG keyring)? Also in a couple of brief tests I ran, I kept getting prompted for the passphrase on the terminal, but that could be because of my paranoid gpg config (I disable passphrase caching completely). That would definitely break things in a non-interactive scenario...

Another way to trap errors would be to set [`gnupg_seterrormode()`](http://php.net/gnupg_seterrormode) to `ERROR_EXCEPTION` or similar to see what's actually happening...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, problem was Apache didn't have access to the `home_dir` of gnupg. Create a folder `/var/www/.gnupg`, set `www-data` as owner and initialize the gnupg like this

```
gnupg_init(array("home_dir" => "/var/www/.gnupg"));
```